# "Now can" or "Can now"?

Tags: american-english, syntactic-analysis

Which of the following sentence is correct?

- Buyers **can now** pay using a credit card.
- Buyers **now can** pay
  using a credit card.

Thanks

Comment: Either is okay, and they mean the same.  Also, "now" could come first.

Answer (score 2):

Both are grammatically correct, however "Buyers can now pay using a credit card" sounds the best to my ear.  The phrasing "Buyers now can pay using a credit card" sounds a little stilted and unnatural to me.  Instead, I would probably say, "Now buyers can pay using a credit card."

Also, if this is in North America, consider replacing "Buyers" with "Customers."  We generally use "Customers" to refer to people who are buying things from us, and "Buyers" to refer to our internal staff who are responsible for Buying things on behalf of the company, like the Product that we might resell to our "Customers."